# Automorphism group of a Lie group $G$ vs that of a covering group $\tilde G$: same or not?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, automorphism-groups, covering-spaces

Is it **true or false** that the Inner (Inn), Outer (Out) and Total (Aut) Automorphism of a Lie group $G$ is the same as the covering group of the Lie group, say $\tilde G$ (regardless of how many types of covering groups of $G$ has:
$\tilde G_1$, $\tilde G_2$, $\tilde G_3$, ... )?

Note that Inn$(G)=G/Z(G)$, so this seems to be true for the inner automorphism,
since we have
$$\text{Inn}(G)=G/Z(G)=\tilde G/Z(\tilde G)=\text{Inn}(\tilde G). \tag{1}$$
Also
$$
\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Inn}(G) \rtimes \text{Out}(G), 
$$
so we only need to prove
$$
\text{Out}(G)=\text{Out}(\tilde G) (?) \tag{2}
$$ to show that
also $$\text{Aut}(G) =\text{Aut}(\tilde G) (?)\tag{3}
$$

---

For example,

1. For the $G=SO(3)=PSU(2)$, there is a double cover $\tilde G =SU(2)$, such that
   indeed
   $$\text{Inn}(PSU(2))=\text{Inn}(SU(2))=PSU(2)=SO(3).$$
   Also
   $$\text{Inn}(PSU(2))=\text{Inn}(SU(2))=PSU(2)=SO(3).$$
2. For the $G=PSU(N)$, there is a double cover $\tilde G =SU(N)$, such that
   indeed
   $$\text{Inn}(PSU(N))=\text{Inn}(SU(N))=PSU(N).$$
   $$\text{Out}(PSU(N))=\text{Out}(SU(N))=\mathbb{Z}/2.$$
   $$\text{Aut}(PSU(N))=\text{Aut}(SU(N))=PSU(N) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2.$$
3. So ar the following statements generally true?
   eq 1, 2, and 3?
   $$
   \boxed{\text{Out}(G)=\text{Out}(\tilde G) (?), \quad \text{Aut}(G) =\text{Aut}(\tilde G) (?)}
   $$

Comment: It's not true in general. The easiest example is that of the circle $G=\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$. Also have a look at the cases of $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})\times\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ and $G=\mathrm{SO}(4,4)$.

Comment: One can also see that it's not true, because your situation also includes every finite group as $\tilde{G}$ since $\tilde{G} \to 1$ is also a covering. It also shows that $Aut = Inn \rtimes Out$ is false in general. In other words: These kinds of statements should always come with some condition on connectedness.

Comment: In addition to @‍JohannesHahn's [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405534/automorphism-group-of-a-lie-group-g-vs-that-of-a-covering-group-tilde-g-sa#comment1039617_405534) about connectedness, is "Lie group" here meant to be "*reductive* (and connected) Lie group"?  Your examples seem all to be of that flavour.  (Although, of course, as @YCor [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1039586), it's not true even in that case, basically (my gloss) because of non-trivial automorphisms of the centre; but one could talk about what *is* true.)

Comment: My examples are meant to be connected (I should have written $\mathrm{SO}_0(4,4)$, although $\mathrm{SO}(8)$ should work as well).  If $G$ is simply connected and $Z$ is a discrete central subgroup, the automorphism group of $G/Z$ is the group of automorphisms of $G$ preserving $Z$. (In terms of Out: if $Z_G$ is the center of $G$, then $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ naturally acts on $Z_G$ and  $\mathrm{Out}(G/Z)$ is the stabilizer of $Z$.)

Comment: Am I correct that if $\tilde{G}$ is just (1) a double cover or (2) a universal double cover of $G$, say $1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \tilde{G} \to G \to 1$, then we can have the Out$(G)$=Out$(\tilde{G})$ always true? Thus since Inn$(G)$=Inn$(\tilde{G})$, so Aut$(G)$=Aut$(\tilde{G})$ also always true?

Comment: Thanks, @YCor, and others, I suppose the counter examples you mean: $Out(Spin(8))=S_3$, $Out(SO(8))=\mathbf{Z}/2$, and $Out(SO(8)/\mathbf{Z}/2)=S_3$?  Correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct (the latter is denoted $\mathrm{PSO}(8)$).

Comment: But would the counter examples only happen when we are in SO(n,m) or SO(n+m) when n+m=8 then?