# Automorphism group of a Lie group $G$ vs that of a double covering group $\tilde{G}$: same or not?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, automorphism-groups, covering-spaces

Previously there are some counterexamples given in [Automorphism group of a Lie group $G$ vs that of a covering group $\tilde G$: same or not?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/405534/27004) such that the automorphism group of a Lie group  is not the same as that of its covering group $\tilde{̃}$.

I wanted to sharpen the statement by giving some more constraints on the statements and on specific examples:

Am I correct that if $\tilde{G}$ is just

(1) a double cover or

(2) a universal double cover of $G$, (Note: A covering space is a universal covering space if it is simply connected so $\pi_1(\tilde{G} )=0$),

say $$1 \to \mathbf{Z}/2 \to \tilde{G} \to G \to 1,$$
then we can have the Out$(G)$=Out$(\tilde{G})$ always true? Thus since Inn$(G)$=Inn$(\tilde{G})$, so Aut$(G)$=Aut$(\tilde{G})$ also always true?

p.s. I separately give some specific examples in a new post [Automorphism group of indefinite orthogonal Lie group $G=O(p,q)$ vs that of a double covering group $\tilde{G}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/405616/27004)

Comment: The automorphism group of ${\rm SO}_8({\mathbb C}) $ is inner automorphisms $\times$ a cyclic group of order 2, but the automorphism group of its universal cover ${\rm Spin} _8({\mathbb C})$ is inner automorphisms $\times S_3$.

Comment: thanks so much! +1 for this comment, I suppose what you said is true also fo automorphism of SO$_8(\mathbb{R})$ and that automorphism of Spin$_8(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I think it would help a lot carefully to understand why @PaulLevy's [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405614/automorphism-group-of-a-lie-group-g-vs-that-of-a-double-covering-group-tilde#comment1039880_405614) here, which is in important ways the same as @‍YCor's [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405534/automorphism-group-of-a-lie-group-g-vs-that-of-a-covering-group-tilde-g-sa#comment1039586_405534) on your other question, goes wrong—"bad" (for your purposes) things can happen on the centre, and you might test future hypotheses against such bad behaviour.

Comment: Also, I am almost positive that you want to assume $G$ reductive, since otherwise I believe that your implicit assumption that $1 \to \operatorname{Inn}(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(G) \to \operatorname{Out}(G) \to 1$ splits need not hold.

Comment: I already gave a counterexample to this question in a comment to [your previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405534/). Had you tried to read my comment?